# How to determine order of the remainder term of a series for specific problems?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, approximation-theory, perturbation-theory

**Background:**

In the text book I have, in the 'expansion of integrands' part (perturbation theory) the author kept determining the order, but I can't understand how.

For integration of $\sin \epsilon x^2$, the Taylor series is written, $$<first\ three\ terms> +\ O(\epsilon^7)$$ (I haven't gone through the tedious task of typing the first three terms.) Then it is written in the book,

> ...Since $|x|\le1$ and $\epsilon$ is small, the remainder term in the above series is $O(\epsilon^7)$ for all values of $x%$.

In every example, something like this is written. I can't understand the flow of logic here.

I have searched the internet to understand Taylor series and remainder term better, but all I get is theorem regarding this. I want to know how explicitly it is determined just when the series needs to be truncated. I want to know 'when' to truncate, more than 'how' to truncate.

**Question:**

1. In the above example, why is the series truncated after $O(\epsilon^5)$? Why not after $O(\epsilon^3)$ or $O(\epsilon^7)$?
2. What is the relation between $\epsilon$ being small and the order of the remainder term being $O(\epsilon^7)$? If I truncated, say after $O(\epsilon^{3})$, $\epsilon$ was also then small, and then the remainder term would have been $O(\epsilon^{5})$.
3. How to find when to truncate a series for any function? I thought I could truncate any series acording to my need and wish. Seems like, at least in expansion of integrands, I am wrong, there is a logic for that.

Comment: You are correct. It only depends on what order of accuracy you want for your solution. The more accurate the solution, the higher the order of terms you need to keep.

Comment: @David Good to know that I was right. Can you think of any logic behind $\epsilon$ being small and knowing when to truncate? I think I know your answer, but still asking for clarification.

Comment: It all depends. In boundary layer problems in fluid mechanics the $\epsilon$ is the region of the flow which is strongly affected by the solid boundary, and from the physics it turns out to be thin, so there is your $\epsilon$. Generally you solve to zero-th or first-order because after that it gets to computationally intensive. The $\epsilon$ comes from the equation you are trying to solve and the system that equation models.